# Invoke different compiler depending on configuration

Tags: makefile

I'm developing on two different machines at the moment. On one `gcc` maps to gcc 4.6 and there is a `gcc3` for whomever needs a really old version of gcc. On the other machine `gcc` maps to a v3 gcc and there is a `gcc4` command for invoking the newer compiler.

The problem should be obvious - I want a single makefile for both machines, which basically means defining `CC` depending on whether `gcc4` can be found or not.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I don't have much experience with the more complicated parts of makefiles, so I just searched around and couldn't find anything that really fit. I did try amongst lots of other things `$(shell which gcc4)` but that failed because checking for the return value was executed in different shells - seeing the solution now makes that obvious but back then it was just another failed attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick hack you could add a simple shell based check for a gcc4 bin inside your makefile. For example:

```
CC := $(shell gcc4 -dumpversion >/dev/null 2>&1; if [ "$$?" -eq 0 ]; then echo "gcc4"; else echo "gcc"; fi)
<...>
$(CC) -c myprogram.c -o myprogram.o
<...>
```

However, for more mature projects I would recommend consider tools designed for such task in mind ([autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/#introduction)).

Comment: I was playing around with `$(shell which gcc4)` but couldn't figure out how to get the return code (the code apparently got executed in different shells), works perfectly. I'll look into autoconf, but since the only difference is how to invoke the compiler for now the easy solution works fine.